# Why is my £100,000 being converted to 100 and not 100000, possible issue with Regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following code:

```
var totalDecimalList = Regex.Split(total, @"[^0-9\.]+").Where(c => c != "." && c.Trim() != "");
decimal totalDecimal = decimal.Parse(totalDecimalList.First());
```

Via my debug session

```
totalDecimal = 100 and not 100000
```

So the "," is obviously the cause of the issue and an incorrect regex in first line ie

```
@"[^0-9\.]+")
```

How can I correct this Regex please to account for the commas?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried adding the comma into [^0-9\.] ? e.g [^0-9,\.]

Comment: Thank you, that has sorted it. Pretty simple :) Please put as answer and I will mark up. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Better yet, let the built in parse function do the work for you:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace StackOverflow_CurrencyParsing
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string total = "£100,000.00";

            decimal totalDecimal = decimal.Parse(total, NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-gb"));

            Console.WriteLine($"Total: {totalDecimal}");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the comma into the bracket expression of characters to match
e.g

```
 [^0-9,\.]
```